# Sorting sets (not a single set)

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures, set

I have a number of sets with each set representing the unique items in a single data file. Some of these sets are subsets of others, some are identical.

Is there a primitive or a module that lets me sort the sets such that I get something like

```
A <= B <= C <= D <= E
```

et cetera for the sets A, B, C, D, E, F?

I.e. sort *not* the items from a set, but instead sort the sets themselves by their relation as subsets and supersets of each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put them in a list and sort them. If a set is a *subset* of another set their `<=` relationship is True, and this extends to sorting. In other words, what you want is the *default sort order already*.

Demo:

```
>>> A = {1, 2}
>>> B = A | {3}
>>> C = B.copy()
>>> D = C | {4}
>>> A <= D
True
>>> [B, C, D, A]
[set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 3, 4]), set([1, 2])]
>>> sorted([B, C, D, A])
[set([1, 2]), set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

To be explicit: two sets that are not a subset of the other return False for all ordering operations, and their *relative* order when sorted won't change. This means that disjoint sets in the sequence will throw a spanner in the works, as they violate the expectation of total ordering sorting has.

Comment: Aha, didn't realize this was possible. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure the results of this sort are terribly useful, since the order is not well defined (the sort operation will not fail, but the order is somewhat arbitrary). That's because many sorts (including Python's timsort) assume their values are totally ordered. That's not true of `set`s, where you can have `a < b and not c < b` but you can't conclude `a < c`. Try `a,b,c = {1},{1,2},{3}`, then `sorted([b,c,a])`. `b` will appear in the output before `a`.

Comment: @Blckknght I explicitly state this limitation in my answer.

Comment: @Blckknght made it a little more explicit.

Comment: Ah, I may have misread the question's description of the sets. If there are no disjoint sets in the list, `sorted` will indeed work just fine.